# OWIN Cookies and IP address

Tags: asp.net, owin, asp.net-identity

When I am testing the samples in VS 2013 out the box, they work fine with localhost or when accessing from localhost - the cookie is generated fine and saved in domain localhost.

I then wanted to do some testing from iPad on Safari, so I enabled IP address access on IISExpress. When I access my test website via IP address 10.0.0.x:port, no cookie is provided.

I have the stock standard line:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
```

How can I "name" my cookie for MS Identity to use so that regardless of the browser domain name "localhost" "IP" or "XXXX" that it will still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why this did not work initially. I am still playing around with this. But i changed the startup cookie config to (in Startup.Auth.cs):

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
        AuthenticationType = "ABC",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        CookieName = "ABC"
    });
```

And i then modified the following line in SignIn (IdentityModels.cs)

```
 var identity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, "ABC");
```

And it started working.